Manhwa where the female lead is a tyrant who is executed and reincarnates into a child; she decides to be good in this life
The female lead (FL) in her first life is a villainess and she falls in love with the original male lead (OG ML) or like is obsessed with him. And there's like a crew; it's her brother, the OG ML and the original female lead (OG FL).

Villainess / brother - blonde
OG ML - black / dark hair
OG FL - pink hair

The story progresses, she becomes a tyrant, kills her brother, forces the ML to marry her but he kills himself. Forgot what happened to the FL; she's probably dead.
She was actually being manipulated by another character (second life male lead (ML)) who just wanted her affection or whatever. The people were getting sick of her, overthrew the government, and she was executed. This guy, the second life ML, was there.

Second life ML - white hair; he's the hidden son of a noble family but is more talented than his brother.

Then she reincarnates (could be because of the second life ML) and decides she'll be good to everyone. She is super-scared to do anything wrong around the first life ML and doesn't wanna get close to her brother because she thinks she'll hurt them.
That's kinda all I read up to...

Reading between the lines, it sounds like the MC is transmigrated into a novel. Is that correct? Also, do you recall roughly how many chapters you read?

My first guess for "blonde tyrant/villainess" and "manipulation" would be The Villainess Is a Marionette. I don't think the other hair colors match, but could you explicitly rule it out?

@qazmlpok XD The hair colors seem to match but that's not the one I'm looking for unfortunately

@LogicDictates MC didn't transmigrate into a novel, they went back in time... and I read around 10? chapters

Was it full colour? And did you read it in English?

@LogicDictates Yes to both

Is this The Tyrant Wants to Be Good...?

Nothing was ever handed to Dorothea Millanaire. No attention, no love, no power. So she decided to take them for herself… with her sword! She accepts her fate when she is executed for being a bloodthirsty tyrant, only to wake up... as a child?! This is her second chance. She must not repeat history. She must be good.


The story is set in the Empire of Livera.
The protagonist is Princess Dorothea, daughter of Emperor Karnon Millanaire and younger sister of Crown Prince Raymond. All three have blond hair.
In her first life, Dorothea killed her brother and usurped the throne, becoming a tyrant. The man she loved, Theon Freede (who has black hair), was forced to marry her, but he loved his childhood friend, Julia Delevine (who has pink hair), and took his life after Dorothea had her killed. As Empress, Dorothea's right-hand man was Ethan Bronte (who has silver hair), but he ended up betraying her, leading to her execution.
Dorothea then regresses back to her childhood and attempts to be a good person this time around, correcting the mistakes she made and atoning for the many deaths she caused in her previous life.
You can read the full manhwa at WEBTOON.
